# how to accept-answer/ vote and why-aren't- Qs-numbered

Tags: support

I am new here and I love it. But some of the usage instructions are as clear as mud. I can accept an answer to my Q, I can vote on a Q, but where does it say HOW? I also wonder why  Q's aren't numbered.

Comment: See also: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)

Comment: Questions are numbered. Yours is #21193 on this meta site. Look at the address bar.

Answer (score 4):

Near the top-right edge of your browser window you should see a help menu. Try the first item, [Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), and you'll see that the page explains what you want to know. As for numbering the questions, why would that be useful at all when you can search by any set of keywords of your choice?

[image]